# Virtual host CustomLog file size

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, virtualhost

I'm running the following CustomLog in my virtualhost:

```
CustomLog /var/www/website/requests.log combined
```

All HTTP requests are logged into this file. Everything is working fine only I want to limit the max file size for this file. Eventually this logfile is full and takes up many GB's causing the server the crash because it runs out of diskspace. Apperantly it logs alot of requests.

I want to limit this file to only log the requests from 2 months ago and delete the rest. Or just limit the file size so it cannot extend beyond x GB. Do I need to use logrotate for this? Cannot find a quick awnser online what is best for this scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using? If you are using Linux you should be able to use `logrotate`

Comment: Im using Centos 8

Comment: Use `logrotate` then.